# How to create Autoincrement column in SQLite using EF core?

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-core, auto-increment, .net-standard-2.0

I am using Entity Framework Core 2.0 for Sqlite code first in my [UWP and .NET Standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/uwp/getting-started) app. My model has an entity of type Primary Key integer which should be served as auto increment according to [SQLite documentation](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html). But in real for every row that Identity column is getting 0 as a value.
Please help because i found no helping material related to this issue.

This is my property without any data annotaion.

`public Int32 No { get; set; }`

I have used fluent API

```
modelBuilder.Entity<TurnosGeneral>()
            .HasKey(c => new { c.No, c.Cod_Turno });
```

And value is inserted here

```
db.TurnosGenerals.Add(new TurnosGeneral { Cod_Turno = numeroTurnoTextBlock.Text });
```

`db.SaveChanges();`

For every row inserted c.No is 0.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> My model has an entity of type Primary Key integer which should be served as auto increment

The problem is that the property in question is *not* a PK, but a *part of a composite* PK, in which case it's not considered as auto generated by convention, as explained in the [Generated Values Conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties#conventions) section of the EF Core documentation:

> By convention, **non-composite** primary keys of type short, int, long, or Guid will be setup to have values generated on add. All other properties will be setup with no value generation.

You need to specify that explicitly:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<TurnosGeneral>()
    .Property(e => e.No)
    .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
```

**Update:** The above is the general approach applicable for most of the databases. But SQLite supports AutoIncrement [only for column of type INTEGER PRIMARY KEY](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html), hence this is not EF Core limitation. Either don't use auto increment or make it non-composite PK.

Comment: I have already tried this and always got an error of " SqliteException: SQLite Error 19: 'NOT NULL constraint failed: " Which means instead of auto generation its expecting user generated values on Add. No doubt this works good with sql server in EF 6.

Comment: It's working good with SqlServer in EF Core 2.0.2 as well. Can't find SQLite specific requirement in documentation.

Comment: Ok, I've installed [SQLite EF Core Database Provider)(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/sqlite/) and got this migration (note **Sqlite:Autoincrement**):  `migrationBuilder.CreateTable(name: "TurnosGeneral", 
columns: table => new 
{ 
 No = table.Column<int>(nullable: false).Annotation("Sqlite:Autoincrement", true),
 Cod_Turno = table.Column<string>(nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_TurnosGeneral", x => new { x.No, x.Cod_Turno });
                });`

Comment: But you are right, there seem to be a bug in SQLite provider migration generator which doesn't take that annotation into account. Consider posting an issue in their issue tracker.

Comment: Annotation("Sqlite:Autoincrement", true) is also not working already tried. BTW thanks for your comments. It seems i have to create new issue on github for EF Core for SQLite.

Comment: You are welcome. I've just looked at their `SqliteMigrationsSqlGenerator` code, it appends "AUTOINCREMENT" only for columns which are non-composite PK :(

Comment: But looks like this is actually SQLite [requirement](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html)

Comment: Yes its SQLite requirement and now SQLite is officially maintained by Microsoft.

Comment: The point is, if database does not support it, there is nothing EF Core can do. So we :)

Comment: I can confirm the behavior is still the same, i.e. I do not know how to surpass this with sqlite, i.e. generate an id integer which is not PK

Answer (score 4):

Looks like a bug. Check this : https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/11961

My workaround: Manually change : **.ValueGeneratedNever()** to **.ValueGeneratedOnAdd()** on Id columns in my DBContext class.

Comment: I got this same issue with version 7.0.4 of entity framework. Changing `.ValueGeneratedNever()` to `.ValueGeneratedOnAdd()` fixed the issue. Looks like the bug is back.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the bug consistently when scaffolding so not sure what causes it.

Answer (score 4):

I just ran into this with a SQLite in memory database I was using for testing.  In my case I had a business class with a primary key field called `ContactCategoryId`:

```
public class ContactCategory
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Contact category ID")]
    public int ContactCategoryId { get; set; }
```

And I was also using the fluent approach for the settings:

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ContactCategory> modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.ToTable("CONTACT_CATEGORY", _schema);

    modelBuilder.HasKey(x => x.ContactCategoryId);

    modelBuilder.Property(x => x.ContactCategoryId)
        .HasColumnName(@"ContactCategoryID")
        //.HasColumnType("int") Weirdly this was upsetting SQLite
        .IsRequired()
        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
        ;
```

Commenting out the line for `.HasColumnType("int")` fixed the error for me.

Comment: For me it worked only after I completely removed entity.Property(e => e.Id).HasColumnName("ID");

Answer (score 0):

This is a very dirty hack, depends a lot on your requirements, and obviously it should never use in production. It has some limitations: for example all the inserts must be made using E.F... but maybe it useful for someone.

In my case: I have a lot of integration tests, I can run it using an in memory Sqlite database and sometimes using the real database. To separate the production and test code I have all the code in a new DbContext that inherits from my real DbContext, in the test I inject this new DbContext.

The code: override the SaveChanges methos and call you own code.

```
public override int SaveChanges(bool acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
{
    ProcessSqliteIdentities(ChangeTracker.Entries());
    return base.SaveChanges(acceptAllChangesOnSuccess);
}

public override Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    ProcessSqliteIdentities(ChangeTracker.Entries());
    return base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
}
```

The ProcessSqliteIdentities function seeds the identity columns (and saves the last identity for each entity)

```
//Dictionary to save the last identity for each entity type
private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Type, int> SqliteIdentities = new();

private void ProcessSqliteIdentities(IEnumerable<EntityEntry> entries)
{
    //Just in case
    if (Database.ProviderName != "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite")
        return;

    entries
        .Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Added)
        .Select(e => new
        {
            e.Entity,
            NewIdentity = SqliteIdentities.AddOrUpdate(
                e.Entity.GetType(),
                1,
                (_, currentIdentity) => currentIdentity + 1)
        })
        .Select(e => e.Entity switch
        {
            Customer c => c.CustomerId = e.NewIdentity,
            Book b => b.BookId = e.NewIdentity,
            // Add one line for each of you database types
            _ => (object)null! //Just in case you have one entity with no multiple primary keys
        })
        .ToList(); //Or whatever method you like to force the enumeration of the select
}
```

I hope it helps someone :)