# Adding record with composite key fails NOT NULL constraint in ef core

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework

I am building a finance application and for the sake of storing stock prices I am utilizing the following class:

```
public sealed class Price
{
    public long CompanyId { get; set; }
    
    public long PriceId { get; set; }
    
    public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
    
    public double Value { get; set; }
}
```

generated database context scaffolded with ef core from SQLite is as follows:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Price>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => new { e.CompanyId, e.PriceId });

            entity.Property(e => e.TimeStamp).IsRequired();

            entity.Property(e => e.Value)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasColumnType("REAL");
        });
```

and now I am trying to add a record in such a manner that I am specifying the CompanyId and ef core autoincrements PriceId. For this purpose I have changed the model builder:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Price>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => new { e.CompanyId });

            entity.Property(e => e.PriceId).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

            entity.Property(e => e.TimeStamp).IsRequired();

            entity.Property(e => e.Value)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasColumnType("REAL");
        });
```

However, whenever I am trying to add a record:

```
Context.Prices.Add(new Price{CompanyId = 1, Value = 1234.56, TimeStamp = DateTime.Now});
```

the *SqliteException: SQLite Error 19: 'NOT NULL constraint failed: Prices.PriceId'.* exception is being thrown. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you generate and execute a migration after updating the mapping?

Comment: At first I created a database and then scaffolded it. Now I am making a new migration and making and executing it but result is the same.

Comment: Can you try to delete a db, delete all migration files, including `DbContextSnapshot` and scaffold db basically from scratch? I assume you use code first?

Comment: If I delete a db whats to scaffold then? I dont think I understand you correctly :/ Considering code first I have a concrete generated model that I would like to implement into database. Forgive me for my inexpierience I am a beginner when comes to ef core.

Comment: Could you please share some code where you create `DbContext` and use it later? Is it a desktop app? Do you use dependency injection?

Comment: First I have created database with SQLite browser. It's tables and columns. Then I scaffolded it. I am basing on the Context.cs and models generated by this scaffold. It's a web api app.

Comment: Then make sure you call `DbContext.Database.Migrate()` in `Startup` class

Comment: All the same, NOT NULL constraint fails :/

Comment: Artur if it's not for work could please share a link to repository? I'd like to try out myself

Comment: https://github.com/ArturMarekNowak/FinanceWebApp/tree/feature/RequestingService

Comment: It seems to be an unfixed bug: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49592274/how-to-create-autoincrement-column-in-sqlite-using-ef-core