# How to implement auto-increment for non-PK long field in SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework

I have this piece of database schema which is working perfectly fine for SQL Server:

```
builder.Property(b => b.FieldName)
    .UseIdentityColumn(1, 1)
    .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
```

But once I tried to switch to SQLite for testing I got error: `SQLite Error 19: 'NOT NULL constraint failed: TableName.FieldName'`.

In my understanding `ValueGeneratedOnAdd` does not work in SQLite for non-PK fields (in SQL Server it does auto-increment).

Is there some workaround to resolve this?

Comment: SQLite does not support the `AUTOINCREMENT` property for non-primary key columns. To achieve that, maybe you can consider create trigger when insert data

Answer (score 0):

**Note *This answer does not provide an EntityFramework solution, rather it attempts to provide a background of how SQLite handles the automatic generation of unique values that identify a specific row.***

This answer may be of use [How to create Autoincrement column in SQLite using EF core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49592274/how-to-create-autoincrement-column-in-sqlite-using-ef-core)

> Is there some workaround to resolve this?
> Yes and in theory, possibly nothing to do in regards to the schema!

SQLite is quite flexible and thus quite different to other databases.

**The basis of possibly doing nothing**

SQLite for all tables other than virtual and WITHOUT ROWID tables all have a column that is a unique generated integer value. This is the **rowid** column. The column is a hidden column so needs to be referred to explicitly.

**But that @#$% AUTOINCREMENT?**

SQLite in it's endeavour to be able to use the SQL to create the schema from other databases. Has utilised the AUTOINCREMENT keyword/constraint to more closely mimic the intentional use of AUTOINCREMENT, albeit misrepresentative of it's utilisation.

When AUTOINCREMENT is utilised it **MUST BE** for a column that is defined as INTEGER PRIMARY KEY. *(only 1 such column can exist per table)*. When used the constraint/rule is that the value, if automatically generated **MUST** be greater than any existing or ever used value. i.e. there is a guarantee that the value will increase.

- if AUTOINCREMENT is omitted then the generated value, if the highest possible value has been reached, may be a lower unused value. However, in the same scenario (highest possible value has been used), then an SQLITE_FULL exception will result.
- If INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, with or without AUTOINCREMENT, is coded (note that the keyword MUST be INTEGER not INT for example) then the column will be an alias of the **rowid** column.

So in theory you may be able to just use the **rowid** and skip the `.ValueGeneratedOnAdd();` **but** when the value is required extract it by specifying **rowid** *(or **oid** or ***rowid***)*.

Alternately you could specify an integer column as the primary key and make it nullable (if possible i.e. you probably don't want the NOT NULL as wrappers tend to use null when inserting).

Here's a demo showing some of how SQLite generation works:-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS a;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS a (c1);
/* Insert 2 rows where the value in column c1 has nothing at all to do with the rowid */
INSERT INTO a VALUES('anything');
INSERT INTO a VALUES('yet another anything');
/* Now change the rowid(s) to 100 times what they were */
UPDATE a SET rowid = rowid * 100;
/* now insert 10 rows via recursive CTE */
WITH 
    cte1(i) AS (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT cte1.i+1 FROM cte1 WHERE i < 10 LIMIT 10)
    INSERT INTO a SELECT 'xxx'||(i*100) FROM cte1;
/* play around with the maximum possible rowid */
/* add 2 rows one at max the other with generated value NOTE!! no AUTOINCREMENT */
INSERT INTO a (rowid,c1) VALUES
    (9223372036854775807,'maxrowid'), /* specify the MAX possible value for this row */
    (null,'higher then max rowid?????'); /* null!!!!???? SQLite allows null and then generates the value */
/* add another row with generated rowid */
INSERT INTO a (c1) VALUES('another higher than max rowid!!!!!');
/* Output as per typicalll all columns query */
SELECT * FROM a;
/* now add the hidden rowid column to the output */
SELECT *,rowid, oid, _rowid_ FROM a;

/*<<<<<<<<<< TABLE B ROWID ALIAS >>>>>>>>>>*/
/* Add table B now with a column rowid_alias as an alias of the rowid column */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS b;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS b (rowid_alias INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, c1);
/* Populate table b from column c1 only of table a (i.e. rowid and thus alias generated) */
INSERT INTO b (c1) SELECT c1 FROM a;
/* Now show both table a and table b JOINED BY the c1 column */
SELECT b.*, b.rowid AS rowid_from_b, a.*, a.rowid AS rowid_from_a FROM b JOIN a ON b.c1 = a.c1;

/*<<<<<<<<<< TABLE C - AUTOINCREMENT >>>>>>>>>>*/
/* Show the schema for prior to table c */

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS c;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS c (rowid_alias INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, c1);
INSERT INTO c SELECT rowid,* FROM a UNION SELECT * FROM b;
SELECT * FROM c;
SELECT * FROM sqlite_sequence;
INSERT INTO b (c1) VALUES('rowid still has max');
/* NOTE COMMENT OUT THE NEXT LINE IF ENVIRONMENT IS TO BE CLEANED */
INSERT INTO c (c1) VALUES('what about AUTOINCREMENT when max rowid has been used');
DELETE FROM sqlite_sequence;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS a;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS b;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS c;
```

When run (with the SQLITE_FULL failure purposely included) this results in the following outputs:-

**Result 1** typical extract from table **a**:-

[image]

- i.e. nothing at all special

**Result 2** table a along with the hidden **rowid** column:-

[image]

- i.e. an autogenerated value which can be referred to by rowid, oid or *rowid* exists by doing nothing to a standard table.
- note how the rowid's 1616919119006865753 and 2751465668745177295 are generated with other unused random values if the highest value for the rowid has been utilised. NOT APPLICABLE is AUTOINCREMENT (not auto_increment) is used.
- as there is only the one PK index then extract, in the absence of an ORDER BY, is by order of the PK aka rowid. Obviously wise to use ORDER BY and indexes.

**Result 3** table b with INTEGER PRIMARY KEY and thus an alias of the rowid column and table a joined via the c1 column.

[image]

**Result 4** table c with AUTOINCREMENT loaded with rows from table a and table c. NOTE no generated values. :-

[image]

**Result 5** sqlite_sequence as utilised by AUTOINCREMENT :-

[image]

**MESSAGE/ERROR** Due to attempt to insert into table c when highest possible  generated value has been used:-

```
/* NOTE COMMENT OUT THE NEXT LINE IF ENVIRONMENT IS TO BE CLEANED */
INSERT INTO c (c1) VALUES('what about AUTOINCREMENT when max rowid has been used')
> database or disk is full
> Time: 0s
```

- note the message has been altered/handled by the SQLite Tool used (Navicat).

You may wish to refer to https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html

A final warning not using an alias of the rowid (INTEGER PRIMARY KEY) can result in issues as:-

- > The VACUUM command may change the ROWIDs of entries in any tables that do not have an explicit INTEGER PRIMARY KEY.